# Waiting for task to complete nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express route that make a thumbnail of an image, writes it locally to a file and streams it back to the user.

I'm running in cluster mode, and if consecutive requests come they all re-size the image together and write on each other,

I would like the first request to start re-sizing, and the other requests to know there is already as job running and wait for it to complete and then stream it's results.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could give locker a try: https://github.com/bobrik/locker & https://github.com/bobrik/node-locker